# How to install clang-format-7 from bionic-updates universe on 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I would like to install [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/devel/clang-format-7) package: clang-format-7.

I am unable to do so in the usual way. Here is the output of `sudo apt install clang-format-7` (following `sudo apt update`):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang-format-7
```

And here is the output of `apt search clang-format`:

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
arcanist-clang-format-linter/bionic,bionic 0.git20161021-2 all
  clang-format linter for Arcanist

clang-format/bionic-updates 1:6.0-41~exp5~ubuntu1 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-3.9/bionic 1:3.9.1-19ubuntu1 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-4.0/bionic 1:4.0.1-10 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-5.0/bionic 1:5.0.1-4 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code

clang-format-6.0/bionic 1:6.0-1ubuntu2 amd64
  Tool to format C/C++/Obj-C code
```

It does not find version 7.

My `Updates` settings are as follows:
[image: screenshot here].

Finally, here is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep bionic-updates`:

```
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
```

Given that `bionic-updates universe` is in the sources, shouldn't apt be able to find the package?

Alternatively, I know that there are PPAs from which I could get it (namely https://apt.llvm.org/) but I would prefer to solve this issue and get it from Canonical's repos.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Not yet. I made the following observation though: on some other computer with a more recent Ubuntu install (18.04.2 instead of 18.04.1), this issue does not happen, the package can be found and installed. The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep bionic-updates` is exactly the same.

Comment: Well, my system running `18.04.2` and able to successfully located `clang-format-7` you mention. Please upgrade to `.2` by `sudo apt dist-upgrade`